# Proof involving $\limsup$.

Tags: real-analysis

Given sequence {$a_{n}$} and supposing its set of cluster points $S_{p}$ is non-empty and bounded above, prove that $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n} = \inf_{n \geq 1}\sup_{m \geq n}a_{m}$.

I started by setting $x=\inf_{n \geq 1}\sup_{m \geq n}a_{m}$ and $y=\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}$. This then means I would have to show that $y \leq x$ and $y \geq x$, but I'm not really sure how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Which definition do you have for $\limsup$?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! The definition I have for $\limsup$ is as follows:

Assume that a sequence {$a_{n}$} has a set of cluster points and denote $S$ the set of cluster points. If {$a_{n}$} is bounded above, we define the upper limit of {$a_{n}$} as $\sup S$. The upper limit of {$a_{n}$} is referred as the limit superior of {$a_{n}$} and can be denoted $\limsup a_{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

First we will prove that $x\leq y.$ Choose an arbitrary $\epsilon >0.$ Then, there exists $n_0$ such that

$$a_n\leq y+\epsilon,\ \forall n\geq n_0.$$

Note that this is true, because otherwise you can contradict the definition of $\limsup$ by making use of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem (this will help you construct a subsequence with a limit, which is greater that the $\limsup$). Anyway, the inequality above implies that $y+\epsilon$ is an upper bound of $\{a_n\}_{n\geq n_0}.$ Since $\sup_{n\geq n_0}a_n$ is the smallest upper bound of this sequence (this is a standard definition and you can show its equivalence to any other definition), we get that

$$x\leq \limsup_{n\geq n_0}a_n\leq y+\epsilon.$$

Consequently, $x\leq y+\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$. Letting $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, we obtain

$$x\leq y.$$

Now we prove the inverse inequality. Again, we choose an arbitrary $\epsilon>0.$ The definition of infimum (for the sequence of numbers $\{\sup_{n\geq m}a_n\}_{m\in \mathbb{N}}$) guarantees that there exists $n_1$ such that

$$a_n\leq \sup_{n\geq n_1}a_n\leq x+\epsilon,\ \forall n\geq n_1.$$

If $\{a_{m_k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ is the subsequence of $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}},$ converging to $y$, then, we take $n=m_k$ with $m_k\geq n_1$ at this inequality and letting $k\rightarrow +\infty$, we get that $y\leq x+\epsilon.$ We let $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ again and we finally deduce that

$$y\leq x.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's denote $b_n=\sup_{m\geq n}a_m$, note that $b_1\geq b_2\geq b_3\geq \dots$. We have $x=\inf_{n\geq 1} b_n$. We are going to denote $b_n\downarrow x$, since $b_n$ is decreasing and approaching $x$ (Note that in particular $\lim b_n=x$).

**1)** If $z$ is a cluster point, then $z=\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_{k_n}}$ for some subsequence $a_{k_n}$. Since $a_{k_n}\leq b_{k_n}$, we have that $$z=\lim (a_{k_n})\leq \lim b_{k_n}=x.$$ So, $x$ is an upper bound of the set of cluster points. This proves that $y\leq x$.

**2)** Let's prove now, that  $x$ is a cluster point (i.e. $x\in S$), note that this implies that $x\leq y$

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $N>0$. Since $b_n\downarrow x$, we have that there is some $n>N$ such that  $x\leq b_n<x+\epsilon$. Since $b_n=\sup_{m\geq n}a_m$, we have that there is some $m\geq n$ such that $b_n-\epsilon<a_m\leq b_n $.

Hence, we found $m>N$ such that $x-\epsilon<a_m<x+\epsilon$. This proves that $x$ is a cluster point. And consequently $x\leq y$.